# How to write Junit testcases for DAO class using H2 databse mocking JDBC template if I am having too many tables in my actual database?

Tags: java, junit4

```
@Test
public void whenInjectInMemoryDataSource_thenReturnCorrectEmployeeCount() {
    DataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
      .addScript("classpath:jdbc/schema.sql")
      .addScript("classpath:jdbc/test-data.sql")
      .build();

    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO = new EmployeeDAO();
    employeeDAO.setDataSource(dataSource);

    assertEquals(4, employeeDAO.getCountOfEmployees());
}
```

How to do this process for every DAO and for all tables and schemas??

Comment: Hello, what does `getCountOfEmployees()` actually do, runs a query or does some real business logic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.